# Code igniter 3.1.11 router.php not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi guys please advice me as Code igniter 3.1.11 router.php is not working
Its only working for http://maindomain/
but not working for http://maindomain/about instead shows 404 page

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';


$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

.htaccess file below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# This domain inherits the “PHP” package.
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: What web server are you using? If it's Apache, do you have mod rewrite enabled and installed and have you added a htaccess-file to your application? If it's any other web server, have you made sure it's configured correctly to rewrite all url's to index.php? Read more in [the manual](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html).

Comment: its apache have modified the question to include the .htaccess file

Comment: How about my other questions? Is mod rewrite installed and enabled? If yes, did you restart the server after? You should also make sure you have `AllowOverride All` to your vhost config, or the htaccess file will be ignored.

Comment: I have five other websites running codeigniter 3.0.13 and they are all working perfectly. I am begining to think that i made a mistake installing this version of codeigniter. How do i downgrade my codeigniter version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';` will redirect all your requests to `pages/view` irrespective of what `controller(URL)` you write and will be a nightmare to manage all the requests to your site.

Say, you write
`http://maindomain/xyz/something` now because it doesn't expect any parameter after `(:any)`, it goes to `404`

but
`http://maindomain/xyz` will work fine as it satisfies your routing rule.

The reason `http://maindomain` works is because you've defined it as your default controller. You can write your `routes` like this -

```
$route['default_controller']   = 'pages/view';
$route['pages/(:any)']         = 'pages/view/$1'; // this will route any requests to pages/xyz to pages/view/xyz
$route['404_override']         = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

See if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a similar issue I had and I ended up fixing it by editing system/core/Router.php and changing line 396 from:

```
$key = str_replace(array(':any', ':num'), array('[^/]+', '[0-9]+'), $key);
```

to

```
$key = str_replace(':any', '.+', str_replace(':num', '[0-9]+', $key));
```

... not ideal because it isn't upgrade safe but it did the trick for me (CI 3.1.11, PHP 7.4)